# How to authenticate users in Authlogic with usernames that are unique to an account only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

For the life of me, I can't get this to work. I have an application where each account has a unique subdomain. Within that account, users have a unique username but the username may not be unique across the application as a whole.

```
def create
  @user_session = @current_account.user_sessions.new(params[:user_session])
  @user = @current_account.users.find_by_username_or_email(params[:user_session][:username])
  if @user_session.save
    flash[:notice] = "Welcome back #{current_user.first_name}"
    if @user_session.user.account.is_new? && !@current_account.stop_wizard?
      redirect_to :controller => "site", :action => "welcome", :id => "one"
    else
      redirect_to dashboard_url
    end
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

This seems to fail on the `if @user_session.save` line because it validates against the first instance of the username within the database and not against the username that is scoped to the current account.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Robin

Comment: Have you tried simply writing a custom validator that checks the uniqueness inside the specified domain? http://www.paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/33-how-to-write-custom-validation-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I don't have a problem with ensuring uniqueness within the subdomain rather that Authlogic doesn't seem to respect the subdomain constraint when authenticating the user details e.g. when the user session is created with username robinfisher, it should look for the user with that username scoped to the relevant account.

Comment: Ah ok.. I misread your question.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [with scope](http://rubydoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/Session/Scopes/ClassMethods#with_scope-instance_method) option when creating my session was the answer.